# Is it appropriate to only specify the contrasts you are interested in?

Tags: r, contrasts, lsmeans

I am running some contrasts in R using emmeans, and when I specify my contrasts like this:

```
emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Status | Stim | Treatment, adjust = "tukey")
```

I get considerably lower p values when I run all the contrasts and adjust

```
emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Status*Stim*Treatment, adjust = "tukey")
```

What is the "technically" correct way to go about obtaining p-values for multiple contrasts - to specify or not?

Edit: Results

```
$contrasts
Stim = 1, Treatment = None:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.24213 0.0571 57.5 -4.241  0.0002 
 Control - Clinical     -0.16275 0.0571 57.5 -2.851  0.0164 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.07938 0.0571 57.5  1.390  0.3526 

Stim = 2, Treatment = None:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.02744 0.0612 68.7 -0.448  0.8953 
 Control - Clinical      0.00581 0.0612 68.7  0.095  0.9950 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.03325 0.0595 64.4  0.558  0.8425 

Stim = 3, Treatment = None:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.23450 0.0571 57.5 -4.108  0.0004 
 Control - Clinical     -0.05862 0.0571 57.5 -1.027  0.5631 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.17588 0.0571 57.5  3.081  0.0088 

Stim = 1, Treatment = B:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.21838 0.0571 57.5 -3.825  0.0009 
 Control - Clinical     -0.13390 0.0583 61.0 -2.296  0.0640 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.08447 0.0583 61.0  1.448  0.3229 

Stim = 2, Treatment = B:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.03460 0.0600 65.5 -0.577  0.8331 
 Control - Clinical      0.04190 0.0600 65.5  0.698  0.7654 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.07650 0.0571 57.5  1.340  0.3792 

Stim = 3, Treatment = B:
 contrast               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control - Subclinical  -0.23738 0.0571 57.5 -4.158  0.0003 
 Control - Clinical     -0.03662 0.0571 57.5 -0.642  0.7979 
 Subclinical - Clinical  0.20075 0.0571 57.5  3.516  0.0024 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Second Code (small snippet, list is very long):

```
$contrasts
 contrast                                               estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Control 1 None - Subclinical 1 None                -0.24213 0.0571 57.5  -4.241 0.0090 
 Control 1 None - Clinical 1 None                   -0.16275 0.0571 57.5  -2.851 0.3119 
 Control 1 None - Control 2 None                    -0.71711 0.0452 99.4 -15.858 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - Subclinical 2 None                -0.74454 0.0583 61.0 -12.765 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - Clinical 2 None                   -0.71130 0.0583 61.0 -12.195 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - Control 3 None                    -0.20237 0.0413 98.0  -4.905 0.0005 
 Control 1 None - Subclinical 3 None                -0.43688 0.0571 57.5  -7.652 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - Clinical 3 None                   -0.26100 0.0571 57.5  -4.572 0.0031 
 Control 1 None - (Control 1 B)                     -0.01325 0.0413 98.0  -0.321 1.0000 
 Control 1 None - (Subclinical 1 B)                 -0.23162 0.0571 57.5  -4.057 0.0157 
 Control 1 None - (Clinical 1 B)                    -0.14715 0.0583 61.0  -2.523 0.5232 
 Control 1 None - (Control 2 B)                     -0.71877 0.0452 99.4 -15.895 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - (Subclinical 2 B)                 -0.75338 0.0571 57.5 -13.196 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - (Clinical 2 B)                    -0.67688 0.0571 57.5 -11.856 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - (Control 3 B)                     -0.20625 0.0413 98.0  -4.999 0.0003 
 Control 1 None - (Subclinical 3 B)                 -0.44362 0.0571 57.5  -7.771 <.0001 
 Control 1 None - (Clinical 3 B)                    -0.24288 0.0571 57.5  -4.254 0.0086
```

Comment: Show us what you get, because I think there should be fewer comparisons and smaller P values in the first call.

Comment: Updated with the results output for the first code and a small snippet of the second one (since the list was very long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results shown are as I expected -- the opposite of what is stated. For instance, the first contrast is Control - Clinical with Stim 1 and Treatment none. The estimate in both outputs is -0.24213, but the P value is 0.0002 in the first output and 0.0090 in the second -- *larger*, not smaller, than the first output.

The P values are different because they represent adjustments for different families. In the first output, each set of three comparisons is regarded as a separate family of comparisons of the 3 Status levels. Note the annotation at the end says "tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates". The second output regards all 3x3x2 = 18 factor combinations as one family, and the annotation, were it shown, would say that: "tukey method for comparing a family of 18 estimates". The larger the family, the larger the P values, all other things being equal. Note that there are 18 comparisons in the first output; if you had shown them all, there would be 18x17/2 = 153 comparisons. That's a lot more tests.

In usual practice, what contrasts you use depends on which factors interact with which others. If there are no interactions, it's enough to just compare the marginal means of each factor, e.g., `emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Status)` -- for a total of 3 + 3 + 1 = 7 comparisons. If all the interactions are needed, you might consider all simple comparisons -- most easily obtained using `(EMM <- emmeans(model, ~ Status*Stim*Treatment); pairs(EMM, simple = "each")` -- which would give you 18 for `Status`, 18 for `Stim`, and 9 for `Treatment` for a total of 45. But in the end, the most important consideration is which comparisons are actually of interest, taking care that you shouldn't do marginal comparisons of a factor that is involved in any interactions.

Comment: That was an oversight on my part - yes, I meant to say "larger" p values for the second set of contrasts. Tired student brain, my apologies. Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful.

Comment: I gather perhaps "iastatecy" means I'm 130 miles down the road from you, at your cross-state rival's campus

Comment: You would be correct! I'll take Stats help from wherever I can get it, Hawkeye or not ;-)

Comment: Proud of both places

Comment: Both great institutions :-) Of note, I ran your emmeans code and the results are the exact same as my first code, ran each time with the variables re-arranged. This is so nice to know I can get the same results with one line of code instead of three. Thanks so much!

Comment: Dr. Lenth - when converting the contrast results using as.data.frame() the data.frame output is not reporting the correct p-values from emmeans. However, estimate, SE, df, and t.ratio are all correct. Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Comment: Must be that somehow the adjustment is wrong. `as.data.frame()` just calls `summary()`, so if you call `summary()` instead yo'll see the annotations, and that'd be a clue.  Maybe try adding `adjust = "tukey"` to the `as.data.frame()` call???